# Video Thumbnail in original size on Android MediaStore

Tags: android, path, thumbnails, mediastore

I need to get video **thumbnail** from **MediaStore** and I want to show them in 16:9 format.
Actually, with the following code, I can get them in 96x96 size (MICRO_KIND).
I would like to have the path for the thumbnail, so I can have the thumbnail in original format and not the fixed size from the library.
How to do this ?

my code:

```
            long ids = videocursor.getLong(videocursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID));

            ContentResolver crThumb = getContentResolver();
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 1;

            Bitmap curThumb = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                    crThumb, ids, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND,
                    options);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no MediaStore thumbnail in original aspect ratio, only MINI and MICRO_KIND which you have seen.

What I have done is decode a single frame and then scale it using BitmapFactory.

Decoding can be done with [MediaMetadataRetriever#getFrameAtTime](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html#getFrameAtTime()) or [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer).